# Cómo podría hacer una función que recibe tres valores y hace una operación de validación

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

Estoy empezando a aprender python y tengo el siguiente problema:

Programe en Python una función que recibe tres valores A, B, y C y retorna el producto de
los tres valores en valor absoluto. En caso de que alguno de los tres valores no sea numérico
retorna 0, use type para obtener el tipo.

Hice la siguiente función, pero sé que está incompleta, sé que tengo que hacer un if y un else, por si los valores ingresados son numéricos y sino me retorna "0", solo que no sé cómo hacerlo. He intentado con isnumeric() pero me sale error.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
import math

def multiplicacion (a,b,c):
d = math.fabs(a) * math.fabs (b) * math.fabs (c)
return(d)
multiplicacion(-2,4,5)
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puntos a mencionar:

- Tenías algunos problemas de indentación, este lenguaje necesita identificar que sentencias le corresponden a que bloque
- Con una estructura de `if/else` simple puedes manejar si al usuario ingresa como argumentos un valor numérico o cualquier otro
- En otro lenguajes existe el `typeof` para ver que tipo de dato es un parámetro, entonces aquí puedes usar `type` y confirmar si el tipo es igual a `int` para actuar en concencuencia

Código:

```
import math

def multiplicacion (a,b,c):
  if type(a) == int and type(b) == int and type(c) == int:
    d = math.fabs(a) * math.fabs (b) * math.fabs (c)
    return(d)
  else:
    return 0
print(multiplicacion(-20,4,5))
```

*Aclaro que no soy fluido en este lenguaje, por si notan que no se sujeta a ciertas convenciones o buenas prácticas*